# No environment texture but there is one in the reflections

Tags: image, world

...something strange here. I have a scene with a node setup with no environment texture, but in all reflections i see one. The world tab and shader nodes are empty and it should be a dark, grey background. Background under the render -> film section is also not set to transparent. In both evee and cycles. I want to find the texture, since i somehow lost it in a later version of my scene.
...i thought at first i broke blender, since all reflections were gone as i used the undo function. But somehow this secret environment texture, which is not shown anywhere else as in the reflections of the object in the scene.

Any idea why this is happening or/and how i get the exact image background back?

Comment: you may be in Material preview, in that case I think there's an HDRI by default and in the Viweport Shading you need to enable the Scene World option, or the opposite, you are in Rendered preview and you've disabled the Scene World option and in that case it uses an HDRI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the built in HDRI by going to Material Preview, and turning up "World Opacity" under viewport shading options.

[image: WorldOpacity]

If you want to use one of the "preview" HDRI's that came with blender as a render-able HDRI, you can find them (.exr files) in the blender folder at `../2.82/datafiles/studiolights/world`. The default (likely the one you saw) is `forest.exr`. Connect it to your world shader as an environment texture.

If you want other options, there are many free places to obtain them online. One of the most popular is HDRI Haven (https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/).

Comment: Thanks to you all, there was a similar topic, i took this. But it is in fact a bug within an "older" .blend file, that is new enough that we don't see a difference. I cannot change or see the HDRI's that come with blender and when i open the same file a few tests from before, hit on the rendered icon to choose a HDRI from blender the simulated one gets lost. Somehow blender seems to take over when we open the older blend file and sets a background. Thanks for all your help! ;) 

Best way would be to append the object into a new scene with the new blender version features.